# How to check or print which element handle specific event

Tags: html, event-handling, mouseevent

happy new year 2017!!

I want check which elememt is owner of event.

for example, basically mouse wheel event handler(owner) is body element.

if I had several vertical scrollbar, mouse wheel event handler will be changed.

please tell me how to print event owner(especially mouse wheel event).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`event` Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) has several properties. You are looking for `currentTarget` or `target`, depending on how you registered the event handler and which element actually called it.

You can play with them to see.